# windows file set the system path via batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to run a python script from any folder.
I have python installed in

```
c:\Python27\
```

I have the script runme.py installed in

```
C:\Users\XXX\rtc_sandbox\YYY\Tools\TTT\RRR
```

I switch into first folder (from cmd with cd command) and enter

```
set PATH=%cd%;%path%
```

I switch into second folder (from cmd with cd command) and enter
    set PATH=%cd%;%path%

Now for this cmd session global windows path indeed path is modified by typying path on the cmd. It should know where python.exe is and runme.py is

When i go to a random folder C:\ for example  using cd command inside the cmd.exe prompt i get this

```
C:\>python runme.py
python: can't open file 'runme.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\>
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: The cmd processor is only searching for the python because that is the program it has to execute.  The python script you are running is an argument passed to python.exe.  What you should do is associate .py files to execute with python and then all you have to do is type the python script file name at the cmd prompt and it will execute.

Comment: i don't have admin rights so i cannot associate anything

Comment: Then, if your working directory is not where the script is located, you will have to specify the full path to the script.